# OpenSource Document Management

Tags: mysql, document-management

I'm looking for Web-based, Opensource, PHP-MySQL Document Managment for my organization with these features:

- Features :

  - Full text searching
  - Document Metadata
  - User access previledges
  - Document history
  - Database backup
  - Upload document
  - Document upload with some
  - Document Categorization by its type
  - Document Categorization by company names (it will be used by organization subsidaries)
  - It allows user to share document link
  - Automated User, File, and Activity report
- Well, it should be free too :)

We need it to run on PHP and MySQL due to the current server setup. I've checked some of demos such as Ajaxplorer, OWL, LetoDMS, DocMGR, Maarch Archiving DMS, OpenDocMan, and KnowledgeTree (Demo).

I concluded that KnowledgeTree is the best choice that I found, but since they ended the Community Edition, it will be hard for us to manage the future problem. I tried to install it on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and get stuck with several dependency of PHP 5.2. The IT Departement will mantained it independently, so I try to find the best choice for them, both of the community support and the server requirement.

Is there any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: [Alfresco](https://developer.alfresco.com/) is a big player missing from that list.

Comment: I asked to implement PHP based infrastructure that time. So I exclude Java based players.

Answer (score 6):

If your requirement is to use a document management system with PHP and MySQL you could use [OpenDocMan](http://www.opendocman.com/), otherwise, if you have more space you should try [LogicalDOC](http://www.logicaldoc.com) (MySQL+Java) which integrates a great search engine (Lucene)

Answer (score -1):

You can try LibreOffice or OpenOffice.org
You can try also using MS Office with Wine, but it won't provide you full stability or functions.

Comment: Since when cam you use OpenOffice, LibreOffice or MS Office for managing documents? Please explain how this can be done...

Comment: well, as I explained, I need the web-based system.

Answer (score -1):

A simple google search for open source office suite popped up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_office_suites

Found two things that might interest you:
1. [FengOffice](http://www.fengoffice.com/web/) Previously known as OpenGoo. Uses PHP, MySql and Apache
2. [Tiki Wiki](http://info.tiki.org/tiki-index.php) Uses PHP, MySql and Apache

Both allow collaboration.

From a rough go through of the website, I think, you should give FengOffice a try. Do post your thoughts if you try them.

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm looking for a document management system/ enterprise document system like alfresco or knowledgetree. I think it FengOffice and TikiWiki aren't what we need.

Answer (score -1):

Good question!

I am in the search as well, my favored solution at present is resourcespace  http://resourcespace.org/

it is designed for visual media, but seems to work for other media too.

good luck, and if you find other alternatives please report back!